# Добавить UILabel к UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, view, uilabel

Как добавить UILabel к UIPickerView?
У меня есть сам UIPickerView на первом скрине. Нужно добавить надписи ч. м. с., примерное изображение на втором скрине.

с [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Используем методы делегата `UIPickerViewDelegate`

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int,  forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let view = UIView()
    // настроиваем view
    let label = UILabel()
    // настраиваем label
    view.addSubview(label)

    return view
}
```

Если нужно только строку менять можно использовать другой метод:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "New Title"
    }
```